# How to use ctypes to call a DLL function with double underline function name?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, private, name-mangling

I'm trying to call a function in a DLL using Python 3.8 with the `ctypes` module.

The function name in the DLL is `__apiJob()`.  Pay attention, this function starts with a double underline.

I want to call it in a self-defined object like:

```
class Job:

    def __init__(self,dll_path):
        self.windll = ctypes.WinDLL(dll_path)

    def execute(self):
        self.windll.__apiJob()

a = Job('api64.dll')
a.execute()
```

But as the function name starts with double underline, with the name mangling function in Python, it will be regarded as a private method. Therefore, when running this script, the `__apiJob` will be renamed to `_Job_apiJob` which results in an error:  `"_Job__apiJob" not found`.

How can I deal with situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can be called with the following syntax as well, and bypasses the obfuscation Python applies to "dunder" attributes of class instances:

```
self.windll['__apiJob']()
```

Example below:

**test.cpp**

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int __apiJob() {
    return 123;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes

class Job:

    def __init__(self):
        dll = ctypes.CDLL('./test')
        self.apiJob = dll['__apiJob'] # bypass "dunder" class name mangling
        self.apiJob.argtypes = ()
        self.apiJob.restype = ctypes.c_int

    def execute(self):
        return self.apiJob()

a = Job()
result = a.execute()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
123
```

As an aside, `WinDLL` is used for DLLs declaring functions using `__stdcall` calling convention in 32-bit DLLs.  `CDLL` is used for the default `__cdecl` calling convention.  64-bit DLLs have only one calling convention, so either works, but for portability keep this in mind.